# How can I create a custom SeekBar with 4 states like Android's Priority?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-seekbar

I am trying to customize one SeekBar to identify the incidence of a problem during the last 6 month, so based on it, I have 4 possible states: none, low, medium, and high.

As I identify on the tittle, I wish to be able to achieve a layout as the below example.
[image: Android Priority]

I tried to put a SeekBar in the layout, and included to it other layout with the expected options. However, it changes the behavior appearance based on the screen size, and became messy. Below, is the used code:

**SeekBar Layout**

```
        <include
            android:id="@+id/options"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            layout="@layout/options"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="11dp" />

        <SeekBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/seekBar"
            android:max="100"
            android:layout_below="@+id/options" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Options Layout**

```
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/optionN"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:text="None" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/optionL"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Low" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/optionM"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingRight="6dp"
        android:text="Medium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/optionH"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:text="High" />

</TableRow>
```

Comment: Did you try setting the `SeekBar`'s max value to 3? So instead of `android:max="100"` use `android:max="3"`, this way it can have four distinct values: 0, 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: try this lib https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2511

Answer (score 0):

Basiclly, You need to override the function onProgressChanged:

In your onCreate function add:

```
seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
```

Your class should implements OnSeekBarChangeListener:

```
class yourActivity extends Activity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener
```

And the function you should override should look like this:

```
int stepSize = 4;
 @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    progress = ((int)Math.round(progress/stepSize))*stepSize;
    seekBar.setProgress(progress);
    textview.setText(progress + "");
}
```